# Flutter : warning with intent android plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, warnings

I am using android_intent: ^0.3.7+3 plugin in my app ,therefore i get this warning message :

```
Note: D:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\android_intent-0.3.7+3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\androidintent\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
```

what can i do to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do anything to solve this as it's coming from the plugin java codes.
It doesn't affect your work in any way and it's common to most early flutter plugins (especially those written in Java).